# Magento 2: how can I remove columns in exported XML from order grid?

Tags: magento2, xml, export

I want to remove columns such as shipping address and billing address from order export xml file.

Answer (score -1):

In grid you are able to see "Column" in top section of Grid. Click on that.
Now Simply Please Unselect column which you don't want in your xml/csv and now export xml/csv. it will show only field which you want to export.

hope this helps you.

Comment: It is not working. Tried it but still getting all the columns in my xml file.

Comment: please check your massExport controller code